# Volusion API generic product export, product image missing

Tags: php, api, e-commerce, volusion

i am using Vollusion Api To get Product information, using the below URL to export data.

[http://www.example.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=mylogin&EncryptedPassword=mypaasword&EDI_Name=Generic](http://www.example.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=mylogin&EncryptedPassword=mypaasword&EDI%5fName=Generic)\Products&SELECT_Columns=*,pe.PhotoURL_Large,pe.PhotoURL_Small,pe.PhotoURL_Large.

This URL Exports other product information to XML file, but not the product Image.

Plzzz help if any one know about it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why there is no image data returned is because you most likely do not have any url data inserted into the PhotoURL_Small and/or PhotoURL_Large field in the admin area of your store for your products. PhotoURL_Small and/or PhotoURL_Large fields are only populated from data in these fields. There is no built in Volusion method to have the image URL's appear within the XML output from a **admin generated** API call.

There is a way to return the image url in the XML output but it requires a different API approach and has nothing to do with the built in Volusion API admin page, all of which is beyond the scope of the question at hand.

**Edit**

Why not run a simple SQL query from the admin section? Home >  Inventory > Import / Export

Assuming a "2t" image size. Change if you want a smaller or larger size.

```
SELECT
    Products_Joined.ProductCode,
    'Config_FullStoreURLConfig_ProductPhotosFolder/' + replace(Products_Joined.ProductCode,'/','-fslash-') + '-2T.jpg' AS Image_URL
    FROM Products_Joined
```

Answer (score -1):

The Volusion documentation is very limited and I have found there is a lot of trial and error in trying to get the data from the database that I needed.  It seems to not like to return limited columns in a response.  So your query is going to return all columns from the first 100 or so of your products even though you only had limited listed.  Not real useful.  You can add a where clause to your statement and have limited columns returned.  I had to place a letter like "K" into a field that is not being used.  You can do this in your Inventory>Products>Settings>BulkUpdates.  BE CAREFUL, this will directly alter you data.  Place a letter into an unused field for all your products.  Then use this this query
`http://www.yoursite.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=username&EncryptedPassword=Password&EDI_Name=Generic\Products&SELECT_Columns=p.ProductCode,pe.PhotoURL_Large,pe.PhotoURL_Small&WHERE_Column=p.chosenfield&WHERE_Value=K`

This will return all the product with K (which is all of them) and just the columns selected.  Hope this helps

Comment: This answer is not answering the OPs question. He asked how he could get the product image URL for each product not how to limit xml data to specific count or other criteria. Furthermore the OP did not ask anything about bulk updating.

Comment: Passing the url presented by Attarisoft will return all columns in the table for each product listed.  It is a mess of information.  The photo_large and photo_small may or may not have a value but it is returned and hard to read. The xml is so much information and limited to your first 100 products not all your products.  If you wanted to limit which columns are returned (photo_small and photo_large) in the query and get all the products you can do the work around which included a "bulk update" to speed the process.  This is a working example and yes it does answer the question.